# Can't figure out how to position and modify the size of the Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a pomodoro app in flutter right now and I'm almost finished except I can't position and modify the size of the Container that shows the pomodoros text and the number of pomodoros.

`

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  static const twentyFiveMinutes = 1500;
  int totalSeconds = twentyFiveMinutes;
  bool isRunning = false;
  int totalPomodoros = 0;
  late Timer timer;
  // late is a modifier that means that you don't have to initialize the property immediately but you have a promise (a contract) that you will initialize the property before you use it
  // it basically means you'll initializer later

  void onTick(Timer timer) {
    if (totalSeconds == 0) {
      setState(() {
        totalPomodoros = totalPomodoros + 1;
        isRunning = false;
        totalSeconds = twentyFiveMinutes;
      });
      timer.cancel();
    } else {
      setState(() {
        totalSeconds = totalSeconds - 1;
      });
    }
  }

  void onStartPressed() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(
      const Duration(seconds: 1),
      onTick,
    );
    setState(() {
      isRunning = true;
    }); //onTick() will gonna call the function immidiately
  }

  void onPausePressed() {
    timer.cancel();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = false;
    });
  }

  void onResetPressed() {
    timer.cancel();
    setState(() {
      isRunning = false;
      totalSeconds = twentyFiveMinutes; //totalSeconds;
    });
  }

  String format(int seconds) {
    var duration = Duration(seconds: seconds);
    print(duration.toString());
    print(duration.toString().split("."));
    print(duration.toString().split(".").first);
    print(duration.toString().split(".").first.substring(2, 7));
    return duration.toString().split(".").first.substring(
          2,
          7,
        ); //Splits the string at matches of [pattern] and returns a list of substrings.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: Text(
                format(totalSeconds),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                  fontSize: 89,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Center(
              child: IconButton(
                iconSize: 120,
                color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                onPressed: isRunning ? onPausePressed : onStartPressed,
                icon: Icon(
                  isRunning
                      ? Icons.pause_circle_outline_outlined
                      : Icons.play_circle_outlined,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          //child ==> Creates a widget that controls how a child of a [Row], [Column], or [Flex] flexes. Thus, must use child, not children
          //Column ==> Creates a vertical array of children. Thus, must use children, not child
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  iconSize: 100,
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                  onPressed: isRunning ? onResetPressed : onResetPressed,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.restore_outlined,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    //alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Pomodoros',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '$totalPomodoros',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 58,
                            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ], // Flexible alows you to create UIs that don't really have hard coded values like 200 pixels tall or 100 pixels wide
        // alows you to create UIs that are more flexible, more elastic, more based on proportions
        // can specify the ratio so that there is the least difference between the IOS and the Android platform
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Current App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrjSj.png)

I tried to add alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd syntex but turned out it works way differnt than I expected.

[Error version App UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yITQW.png)

child: Container(
alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),

I'm expecting to position the container at the bottom of the UI and resize it a little bigger

[image: sample]

Comment: So you just want to push the last container at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you need to remove all flex values from your flexible widget. Then, add Spacer in between all flexible widgets. In the last widget (Pomodoros Widget) add flex to increase its height. You can also wrap your column with SafeArea to avoid mobiles top status bar and bottom bar (optional). Check the following code if it answers your question:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Container(
                child: Text(
                  format(totalSeconds),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                    fontSize: 89,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Flexible(
              child: Center(
                child: IconButton(
                  iconSize: 120,
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                  onPressed: isRunning ? onPausePressed : onStartPressed,
                  icon: Icon(
                    isRunning
                        ? Icons.pause_circle_outline_outlined
                        : Icons.play_circle_outlined,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            //child ==> Creates a widget that controls how a child of a [Row], [Column], or [Flex] flexes. Thus, must use child, not children
            //Column ==> Creates a vertical array of children. Thus, must use children, not child
            Flexible(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 100,
                    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                    onPressed: isRunning ? onResetPressed : onResetPressed,
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.restore_outlined,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      //alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Pomodoros',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '$totalPomodoros',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 58,
                              color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ], // Flexible alows you to create UIs that don't really have hard coded values like 200 pixels tall or 100 pixels wide
          // alows you to create UIs that are more flexible, more elastic, more based on proportions
          // can specify the ratio so that there is the least difference between the IOS and the Android platform
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: With SafeArea]

Comment: Could you explain why should I remove all flex values and add spacer in between all flexible widgets?

Comment: And it would be great if you could explain how to apply BorderRadius only on top of the Pomodoros Widget and fill the rest of the background showing background color at the bottom with Pomodoros Widget :)

Comment: normally flex widgets will always wrap you widget no matter how much space it needs. Let's say you have 3 items in a column and you wrap all three items with flexible widget, you will notice all of them taking the same amount of space. Now, if you want your 3rd item in the column to take up more space, just only had flex parameter to that flexible widget only. As for Spacer(), it will add space with a default flex of 1 and you can also had flex parameter to your spacer widget. Using spacer allows your device to take space if it is available.

Comment: As for you, see the view you created. You have 4 items in a column and adding spacer after each item made your UI look more cleaner as all spacer widget took equal amount of space between each item. Spacer widget pushes another widget as much as possible. If in a Row widget you have two items and you add Spacer between both of the widgets, you will notice one of your row item is pushed to the start of the row and the other is pushed to the end of the row if enough space is available. If you don't like spacer, you can use sizedbox to add space between items in columns/rows

Comment: As for your other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59840122/flutter-only-top-border-with-topleft-and-topright-border check this out. Play around with widgets to know how widgets interacts.

Answer (score 0):

I solve your issue like this:
Some comments also added for set Container width and set position of text also you can change below code for your ui

```
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Flexible(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            format(totalSeconds),
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              fontSize: 89,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),

      Flexible(
        child: Center(
          child: IconButton(
            iconSize: 120,
            color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
            onPressed: isRunning ? onPausePressed : onStartPressed,
            icon: Icon(
              isRunning
                  ? Icons.pause_circle_outline_outlined
                  : Icons.play_circle_outlined,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      //child ==> Creates a widget that controls how a child of a [Row], [Column], or [Flex] flexes. Thus, must use child, not children
      //Column ==> Creates a vertical array of children. Thus, must use children, not child
      Flexible(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              iconSize: 100,
              color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
              onPressed: isRunning ? onResetPressed : onResetPressed,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.restore_outlined,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                child: Column(
                  //You can change position from here
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Pomodoros',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '$totalPomodoros',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 58,
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1!.color,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ], // Flexible alows you to create UIs that don't really have hard coded values like 200 pixels tall or 100 pixels wide
    // alows you to create UIs that are more flexible, more elastic, more based on proportions
    // can specify the ratio so that there is the least difference between the IOS and the Android platform
  ),
```

I hope it's help you..
Happy Coding :}